# Can someone explain me declare-styleable XML tag in this example and the theory behind its use?

Tags: android, attr, declare-styleable

I'm reading Beginning Android 4 Development and in chapter 5 it talks about *Gallery* and *ImageVievs* and introduces the *declare-styleable* XML tag without explaining its purpose.. I tried to find some info also on the reference, without luck.. For example we have the following:

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?> 
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name=”Gallery1”>
        <attr name=”android:galleryItemBackground” />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**example.java**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {
[...]
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 
        [...]
    }

    [...]

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        [...]
        int itemBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
            //---setting the style---
            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(
            R.styleable.Gallery1); 
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                        R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            [...]
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
            return imageView; 
        }
    }
}
```

I've read the code a few times and I don't really understand the purpose of defining this styleable *Gallery1* with a single *attr* child only with a *name* attribute.. can you help me? Is this *galleryItemBackground* something provided by the system or is it something defined by us? What are we doing in this piece of code?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This tag is part of a set of premade Android attributes defined in [`R.Styleable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html), which can be told apart from a custom styleable tag from the `android:` xml namespace prefix before the attribute name.

This particular attribute is described as:

> The preferred background for gallery items. This should be set as the
>   background of any Views you provide from the Adapter.

You are right, however, that custom attribute tags would require not only the name of the attribute but what its type is, for example adding a custom element to your `attrs.xml` file might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView"> 
        <attr name=”android:galleryItemBackground” />              
        <attr name="myCustomAttr" format="string" /> 
    </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
```

Note the lack of the `android:` namespace on the second attribute as well.

**Edit:**

> Is there any official documentation page that explains in depth this
>   Styleables?

Check out [`R.attr`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) (click for link) for various attributes included in Android.  You do not need to declare a type for them, because they are all already declared.  To know what type has been declared for a particular attribute, find the description for the one you are interested in.  `galleryItemBackground` is, as you may expect, a reference to another resource; other possibilities are booleans, floats, colors, etc.

Additional references: Andtoid uses the `<declare-styleable>` tag to create an [`AttributeSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html). [`TypedArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) is used to parse the `AttributeSet`.

> If the purpose of the code above [...] is simply get a default
>   Drawable for the view's background, couldn't I set the variable
>   itemBackground with getDrawable(android.R.attr.galleryItemBackground)?

In the example, it is hard to see the usefulness of this pattern when there is only one attribute.  You can do what you ask, and it may be easier.  The construct, however, is part of Android's mantra to separate the UI's "look" from its "functionaly" by letting you set certain attributes in xml instead of having to do everything in code.  Take the `View` class, for example.  It has over 30 attributes that can be set in an xml file (size, padding, clickable, focusable, etc); someone making a custom subclass of `View` can set a few, all or none of these attributes in xml and they are automatically handled for you when the view is created.  There are code equivalents to set the attributes if needed, but imagine every time you subclassed `View` you HAD to set all attributes in code instead of having an option to set them in xml.

It would also be a trivial matter to just make your own resources for your classes that do exactly the same thing, however using the built in styles will provide default resources that match the look and feel of the Android framework if you do not override them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still have some difficulties in understanding what the book is doing in the *Java* code snippet I've written in the main post.. the code *itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0)* is retrieving an ID, but which ID is returned since in the XML I'm only defining an *attr name*? Is there any official documentation page that explains in depth this *Styleables*? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If the purpose of the code above and the use of the *styleable* *Gallery1* is simply get a default *Drawable* for the view's background, couldn't I set the variable *itemBackground* with *getDrawable(android.R.attr.galleryItemBackground)*? Can you explain me a bit more?

Comment: Hi, please see edits to the original answer. I hope they clear up your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer... I still have some difficulties in understanding the logic behind *declare-styleable*.. what is `<attr name=”android:galleryItemBackground” />` exactly saying to the *styleable* *MyCustomView*? Is it saying: you have an attribute *galleryItemBackground* which has the same value as *android:galleryItemBackground*? I'm sorry, but the more I read, the more it confuses me O_o

Comment: Thanks, I liked your explanation. It's now clear how it works.

Comment: Can this be used to change the Themes on Runtime?