# Change the font of all the textviews in my application?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-theme, android-styles

I wonder if there is a way to change the font of all the text views in an android application in single time ? By all the text views i mean  programmatically or dynamically created text views and the text views created separately using XML layout files (Drag n drop)?

I know i can create a new theme with different required fonts and use it . But i can only see the theme applies to dynamically created text views within the program but not the one's in XML layout .

Can you please let me know if there is any solution for this or the only option is to change the font of each text view manually.

Comment: For that you have to make your own custom TextView and apply font now use this TextView in whole you application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to extend the TextView widget:

```
public class FontTextView extends TextView {

private String mTypefacePath;

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setAttrs(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setAttrs(context, attrs, 0);
    init(context);
}

public FontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

private void setAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTextView, defStyle, 0);
    mTypefacePath = a.getString(R.styleable.FontTextView_typeface);
    a.recycle();
}

private void init(Context context) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mTypefacePath)) {
        try {
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    mTypefacePath));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // could not create the typeface from path
        }
    } 
}}
```

You also need to define your `typeface` attribute.
Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840548) to see a useful explanation about.